# NumPy and SciPy. Static vs Dynamic loading

Tags: numpy, scipy, lapack, blas, atlas

**TLDR:** Can I use static ATLAS/LAPACK libraries with NumPy & SciPy?

**Background:**

After building ATLAS with LAPACK with the following:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/math-atlas/files/Stable/3.10.1/atlas3.10.1.tar.bz2/download
wget http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.4.2.tgz
tar -jxvf atlas3.10.1.tar.bz2
mkdir BUILD
cd BUILD
../ATLAS/configure -b 64 -Fa alg -fPIC \
    --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=../lapack-3.4.2.tgz \
    --prefix=<ATLAS_INSTALL_PATH>
make
cd lib
make shared
make ptshared
cd ..
make install
```

I got the following files under `BUILD/lib`:

```
Make.inc@  
Makefile
```

`.a` files:

```
libatlas.a       
libcblas.a       
libf77blas.a     
libptf77blas.a  
libtstatlas.a
liblapack.a     
libf77refblas.a  
libptlapack.a
libptcblas.a
```

`.so` files:

```
libsatlas.so*
libtatlas.so*
```

My first question is, why don't I have `.so` (shared dynamic library) files for `lapack` and `cblas`?

My second question is, which of the following two files does NumPy use?

```
libsatlas.so*
libtatlas.so*
```

Finally, if I define:

```
BLAS=/path_to_BUILD/lib/libcblas.a
LAPACK=/path_to_BUILD/lib/liblapack.a
ATLAS=/path_to_BUILD/lib/libatlas.a
```

and add `/path_to_BUILD/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and to the `library_dirs` variable within the `site.cfg` file in NumPy. Would NumPy and SciPy use my libraries? (even though they are static?).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to. Add

```
[DEFAULT]
search_static_first = true
```

to your `site.cfg` file and you should be good to go.